# Compilation error "Undefined symbols" on osx

Tags: c++, macos, g++

I am trying out a very simple cpp program on osx just to get myself familiar with the osx platform, so I am very surprised to encounter any error message.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
  cout << "Hello, world!" << endl; 
  return 0; 
}
```

I compile it by running

```
gcc -Wall hello.cpp -o hello
```

Then I get this 'undefined symbols' message:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccA9oElQ.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccA9oElQ.o
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const", referenced from:
      std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in ccA9oElQ.o
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in ccA9oElQ.o
      std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in ccA9oElQ.o
      std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in ccA9oElQ.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in ccA9oElQ.o
      _main in ccA9oElQ.o
      ___tcf_0 in ccA9oElQ.o
      unsigned long const& std::min<unsigned long>(unsigned long const&, unsigned long const&)in ccA9oElQ.o
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccA9oElQ.o
      global constructors keyed to mainin ccA9oElQ.o
      CIE in ccA9oElQ.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in ccA9oElQ.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccA9oElQ.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:
      _main in ccA9oElQ.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in ccA9oElQ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I do not know if it is related: I have both xcode 3 and xcode 4 installed on my MBP

Here is the version information:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~6/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

System information

```
$ uname -a
Darwin mbp002.local 10.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `g++` instead of `gcc` since you’re compiling a C++ program:

```
g++ -Wall hello.cpp -o hello
```

Alternatively, use `clang++` since Apple haven’t updated GCC in a while and it’s unlikely they’ll ever update it:

```
clang++ -Wall hello.cpp -o hello
```

Comment: @Kiril No, it’s not! ;-) (but yeah, it was)

Comment: @Bevarious: thanks for the answer! When I try 'clang++', I got 'command not found' error. I can call clang though, but it gives me a bunch of error message. (I suppose it is gcc vs g++ kind of issue?!)

Comment: @Anthony You don’t have `/usr/bin/clang++`? It could be the case that you haven’t installed the command-line utilities in Xcode 4, and maybe Xcode 3 doesn’t install `clang++` because C++ support in Clang is rather recent. The command-line utilities are an optional install if I remember correctly.

Comment: Alternatively, get gcc4.6 from macports.

Comment: just an update: in recent versions of xcode the recommended way to call the build tools is through xcrun. So for clang++ it is `xcrun clang++ options`

Answer (score 6):

Run it using g++

```
g++ -Wall hello.cpp -o hello
```

If you use gcc, the C++ libraries are not linked in by default.