# Error when linking C++ program

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile some very simple C++ code and every time I try I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
  ___tcf_0 in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::cin", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::cout", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::terminate()", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)", referenced from:
  _main in ccdb9vrE.o
"___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in ccdb9vrE.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using this command to compile it:

```
$ gcc script.cc
```

And this is the code for the script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        cout << "Please enter your name:\n";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello, " << name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And I do have the latest dev tool downloaded. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Use `g++`, not `gcc`.

Comment: Addison: it's not wise to point at others for your own mistake. Generally one does not simply assume a compiler bug. I edited the title accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compilation error "Undefined symbols" on osx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167040/compilation-error-undefined-symbols-on-osx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use g++ since its a c++ file not a c file ...
it should work that way ...

Answer (score 3):

`gcc` is a name for GNU *C* Compiler executable; as such, it's meant to compile and build C code.
To compile your code as C++, use `g++` executable.

`gcc` will actually compile C++ code (based on file extension), but won't link the resulting binaries properly (due to the ommitted `libstdc++`).

Answer (score 3):

Anyway: none of the answers so far has mentioned the actual reason why linkage doesn't work with GCC but does so with G++. The problem is not in the compilation step but in the linkage. `gcc` doesn't link against the C++ standard library by default, `g++` does.