# C++ : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on MacOS Mountain Lion

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Ok, I just switched to MacOS after a while of Windows/Linux coexistence. I open a simple text editor, write a simple program just to check if everything is all right. I know there are other threads about this error but it just seems that in all the other cases the problem lied in a specific part of their program, which in turn is far more complex than this. I just want to understand why the compiler says what it says even with a simple thing like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "numeri.h"
int main(void)

{

  std::cout << numeri() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

with

```
//numeri.h

int numeri(void);
```

and

```
//numeri.cpp
#include "numeri.h"
int numeri(void)
{
  return (3);
}
```

what I get from gcc helloworld.cpp -Wall is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "numeri()", referenced from:
      _main in cc6WY2MJ.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:
      _main in cc6WY2MJ.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      _main in cc6WY2MJ.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in cc6WY2MJ.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in cc6WY2MJ.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in cc6WY2MJ.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in cc6WY2MJ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

2 cases:

1 - I forgot how to use a simple header (I prefix, I'm a physics student, I can program for what it regards physics and numeric simulations [or at least, I could], but I just don't know that much about linkers-compilers-architecture and this kind of stuff)

2 - something's wrong

Comment: The error isn’s OS X specific at all, you’d get the same problem on Linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compilation error "Undefined symbols" on osx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167040/compilation-error-undefined-symbols-on-osx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ compiler is g++, . Also you need to add numeri.cpp to your commmand line.

`g++ helloworld.cpp numeri.cpp -Wall`

Comment: wah, thanks ^^ sorry for the lame question, unfortunately I got some serious holes in my programming knowledge, and finding the answer without some help gets hard; on the otherside, retaking books from helloworld results in 99% of the time in non-resolution of the problem and the other 1% in complete bore while discovering that in my books the problem is not addressed at all : S